# Plant with a single upward-pointing orange flower at the tip of the stem?

Tags: identification, flowers, bulbs, lily

Grew in TX right before fall got cold. I'm hoping they grow again in spring but a squirrel has been messing in my pots.

[image: orange]

Answer (score 4):

It's one of the Asiatic Lilies, not sure which variety. There's a similar example here http://www.overthegardengate.net/garden/archives/template.asp?LinkID=596 though I think yours is more orange than the bronze one pictured. Its a bulb, so unless the squirrel has dug it up, it should flower again next year.

Comment: I have it in a big pot with my money tree, they've really dug in there and I can't tell if their still there. But I'll cross my fingers. Lol thanks for the info!

Comment: They're pretty large bulbs, easily twice the size of, say, a daffodil bulb

Comment: These where about the size of my thumb.

Comment: @Hush564...just an aside.  All lilies are fatally poisonous to cats.  And for some weird reason cats are attracted to munching on them.  No problem if you've got indoor cats (thank you in advance) but if out of door kitties, if your cat comes home sick you can expect that they've either eaten mouse bait or lilies.  I recently this past decade learned this and I am a huge cat person as well as a lily lover...out of door cats become the neighborhood cats, grrrrr.  Looks like an asiatic lily to mesef too.

Comment: And don't worry about the squirrels!  The squirrels are planting acorns, peanuts an other nuts.  Or they are digging up their already planted treasures.  They wouldn't bother your bulbs as long as they were well fed.  Peanut plants are beautiful...

Comment: @stormy oh thank you :) I don't have a cat just a puppy, but I keep all my plants off the ground!

Comment: That information was not well advertised.  Puppy's eat ANYTHING.  What kind of a puppy have you got...?  There are lots of other plants that are poisonous to us and other animals.  Just supervision is necessary to prevent a heart break...

Comment: Squirrels do eat lily bulbs - when you say the bulb was the size of your thumb, you mean when you planted it in the first place? That would explain why the flower and its stem looks a bit small and weak... buying bigger bulbs means bigger flowers!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a Siberian Lily to me (*Lilium pensylvanicum*) [Dave's Garden](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/111310/#b)